# UITabBar Image is not clear

Tags: ios, ios8, uitabbar

I just recently got a new set of icons for my app (from an external designer) and I am trying to implement them, but for some reason it ends up looking like this (the new icon is the one in the middle):

[image]

I have tried setting the image of the tab bar to have `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal`, but that's given me no luck.

Here's the icon (it kind of blends into the background but its a white envelope):
[image]

Any reason why this is happening and how I can fix?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding? (cmd+shft+k, then cmd+r)

Comment: @rebello95 that didn't work :(

Comment: take a look at my answer, I figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was setting using `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal` for the tabbar image in the `awakeFromNib` method...that seemed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the entirety of your image is *opaque* - at least part of it needs to be *transparent* to appear as you want it to.

In the below image (since the entire thing is white now, it's directly below this text), I have removed the black line and made that transparent. I then added this image to a tab bar, and it worked fine for me.

[image: Mail Icon]

Here's the [link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUeca.png), as well.

Comment: i found out an easier way...see my answer :)